# Max-min Markov blanket feature selection: R code error

Tags: r, feature-selection

I am using Max-min Markov blanket algorithm for variable selection in `R` from `MXM` package. Following is my code:

```
library(MXM)

dataset = read.table('data.txt', na.string = c("", "NA"), sep = '\t', header = FALSE)
dataset = dataset[, colSums(is.na(dataset)) == 0]
D = as.matrix(as.data.frame(lapply(dataset, as.numeric)))
target = read.table('class_num.txt')
target = c(target)

aa = mmmb(target, D, max_k = 3, threshold = 0.05, test = "testIndFisher", user_test = NULL, robust = FALSE, ncores = 2)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in unique(as.numeric(target)) : 
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

According to the [mmmb manual page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MXM/versions/0.9.7/topics/The%20max-min%20Markov%20blanket%20algorithm) my dataset `D` is a matrix of continuous value of dimension `(95933 x 85)` and my `target` is a vector of `[0, 1]` of size `95933`.

Can someone help me understand the error?

Comment: Note that the MMMB algorithm has been shown to not always produce the true Markov blanket of a node. See the 2006 article "Towards scalable and data efficient learning of Markov boundaries" by Pena, Nilsson, Björkegren, Tegnér. Your alternatives would be the algorithms PCMB or IPC-MB (the latter is more efficient), if you can find any implementation though...

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:
The `target` is a list instead of an array. The following line solved the issue:

```
target = array(as.numeric(unlist(target)))
```

Thanks!